# RESTful API Client Interactions

Tags: php

So I am writing an API, and I am fearful that the code I am writing is going to become messy very quickly.

Some pages I need to be fetching data from several different resources from the API, and I am ending up with a whole bunch of try and catch statements everywhere. For example:

```
$topic_id = 100;
try
{
    $topic = AwesomeAPI::get('topics/' . $topic_id);
    $parts = AwesomeAPI::get('parts?topic_id=' . $topic_id);
    try
    {
        // Get another resource here
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        // Error
    }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    return Response::error('404');
}
```

I am confident that this code is quite messy, and it gets even worse if I have to loop through a resource and grab another resource in the loop. Yuck.

I am wondering how to best approach client interactions with an API in a neat fashion.

Comment: In my opinion you should have all your API logic inside a class and therefore inside methods. So instead of writing code like the one posted, you can write something like this: `$api = new AwesomeAPI();
$topic = $api.GetTopic($topic_id); . . . `

Comment: Right, of course! And handle exceptions within the methods?

Comment: That depends on how you want to handle the exceptions. If you catch them within the API, the API should be able to return an error message  and the application should also be able to retrieve that message and do something about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented before, in my opinion you should have all your API logic inside a class and therefore inside methods. So instead of writing code like the one posted, you can write something like this:

```
$api = new AwesomeAPI();
$topic = $api->GetTopic($topic_id);
```

And your *AwesomeAPI* class could look something like this:

```
public class AwesomeAPI()
{
    public $topic_url = 'somewebsite.com/topics?id{0}';

    function GetTopic($topicId)
    {
        //Some code here
        $response = 'Some response (could be a JSON Document)';
        return $response;
    }
}
```

This way your code in the application will be more elegant and clear.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Simple, but helpful. Thank you very much!